# Finding the main content of Webpage using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I've a sting htmlSrc containing the entire html content of the webpage?
Is there any way to find the main content of the webpage?

What is the page all about using JavaScript?

Comment: What is the "main content" of the webpage? This changes from site to site. If you can identify a container object in the DOM for the site you are looking to target (e.g. sometimes there is a #content div or something similar) you can pull just the contents of that container.

Comment: To extend upon @binaryatrocity's answer, you should also familiarize yourself with basic HTML/DOM structure, they will help you discover what element you need to access your information with.

Comment: @ binaryatrocity.i want to find the similarity between two webpages. based upon content of web page ive the entire webpage content in two strings.

Comment: You'll have to get more specific than that? What exactly are you trying to compare? Images? Text? Layout? You will end up writing logic code to differentiate data between two pages so the more you can narrow down the actual objects in each page you want to compare the easier it will be for you. Can you give us a better explanation of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @amoghpc - If by find similarities between the two you mean code-wise you _could_ do go through the DOM and comapre them with JS **but** if you mean compare the context of the two like `1` is about dogs and `2` is about cats, JS will not help you there.

Comment: if iam trying to remove all the HTML tags and functions. I can able to get the page content right? like what the webpage is about?

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about finding content such that you can differentiate what two websites are about I would suggest finding text within HTML tags and comparing them. You can maybe search for different tags like  and parse the text between the tags. Or maybe  tags to find the headings.